# rails polymorphic nested comments - cant delete them

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, comments, polymorphism, nested-routes

here my git https://gist.github.com/774510

the problem is if I'm using `method:destroy` in the `_comments.html.erb` I get sent to `articles/1/comments`, where no route matches, furthermore the comment doesn't get deleted

if I use `method:delete`, I get routed to the right page `articles/1`, but instead of deleting the comment, my app creates a new one `:/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to tell rails that the comment is nested under articles OR just delete the comment in the comments controller:

1.)

```
# routes.rb
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

2.)

```
# _comments.html.erb
<%= link_to 'delete' comment, :method => :delete %>
```